# How to make universal resizing?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, xcode6

I have made a simple scroll view which contain 5 images everything works fine.
Initially I changed the position of the view to middle of page.

But when I run this app in iPhone 5 i get some extra space at left. How can i remove it to work on both phone.

How it looks on iPhone5

[image]

How it looks on iphone 6

[image]

Comment: Add constraints - Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide, Fixed width and height

Comment: [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(750, 0) animated:YES];    i am using this line to move at 750 is their any method by which the xcode automatically determines the position . i.e., Page 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the interface builder, definitely use auto layout. Apple has some great documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you are doing this programmatically, I recommend basing your view frames relative to the view. For example, instead of setting a width to 400, use self.view.frame.size.width.